# Advanced criteria find blanks / non-blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have successfully used the following to filters for    ``` ="=" (Blanks only) and ``="<>" (Non-blanks only) ```

However it isn't working with a large range for some reason. If I look for a value, ie `="*CC"`then the filter is applied as expected.

Any ideas as to why my Blank and Non-Blank filters might be failing?

Cheers

** LATEST UPDATE **
Am pretty sure the underlying issue is that the value of the column I want to filter is the result of a formula! Anyone know how to handle that?

** UPDATE **
This is a partial view of the data I want to filter (it's a ListObject)
[image]

Here is the criteria range. It's located on a separate worksheet (which shouldn't matter, and again, is working fine searching for a given value (ie "LNG")

[image]

And finally, this is a picture of the desired result of filtering out blanks:
[image]

I can easily get this with AutoFilter of course, but this is a large table and I am using VBA to switch between different analytical views. The AdvancedFilter is more appropriate in this context.

** UPDATE **
I have the same issue whether I apply the filter manually or via code, which further leads me to believe there is something flaky about the filter itself. The code has been successfully tested, and so in fact has the filter on a simple table.

I tried changing the type of the 'Position' column cells (currently it's Text). Just a head scratcher at the moment

Comment: your question isn't clear now, please explain better where the criteria doesn't work. (both range description and function where you use it) Some sample data would help too.

Comment: @MátéJuhász. See update

Comment: thanks. And where it fails? do you have any pattern when filtering doesn't work as expected? Do you have the same issue also when you set the filter manually or only through the macro? (if it's only VBA related, then please also post it's part where filtering is done) ... These are all necessary to understand your problem.

Comment: @MátéJuhász. See update

Comment: Does `=<>""` give any better results?

Comment: Haven't tried that, although the syntax looks off (should be more like ="<>"""" and then you get into a double quote issue). Have you tested this?

Comment: @Berryl: You mentioned it was working, but it doesn't work now. But still didn't posted any sample data. From your screenshots it's not clear how exactly you do the filtering and what exactly the issue is (e.g. Which are the rows not filtered correctly). I can just repeat, without understanding your problem we can't help!

Comment: @MátéJuhász. The problem is clearly defined and solved in the solution below I posted below. Please post a better one if you have it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**:
The value in the column I want to filter on is the result of a formula which either gives a value or an empty string "".

Using ="<>" is the right way to get Non-Blank but Excel is not considering the empty string to be Blank!

**A SOLUTION**:
For lack of knowing a criteria friendly way of saying something like ="vbNullString", I just added another column which evaluates the "Y" if the column I really want is not blank. After hiding the column, I can Filter on that and get the results I need.

Please post if you know a way to get Excel to recognize the empty string tho!